# Responsive, Easy-to-Edit Org Chart

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, orgchart

I have been scouring Google for the better part of my morning trying to find an Org Chart solution for an editable organization chart but almost all of my searches bring me back to [this suggestion.](http://codepen.io/siiron/pen/aLkdE)

Now, this would be fine; however, when I try to remove a department the layout gets completely destroyed and attempting to fix it is time consuming and confusing to me. I liked this layout a lot and I was hoping that this would be the solution I needed but it is currently too hard to work around changes.

I've also look at D3JS but it seems a little bit overboard for what I actually need to do. I only need a few nodes as it is so if it's possible, I'd like an HTML/CSS only solution; however, if JS is the route I need to take that would be ok too.

Again, I'm looking for responsive designs and, so far, nothing but the CodePen example seem to satisfy that.

Thanks ahead of time.

```
/* HTML */
<div class="content">
  <h1>Responsive Organization Chart</h1>
  <figure class="org-chart cf">
    <ul class="administration">
      <li>                  
        <ul class="director">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><span>Director</span></a>
            <ul class="subdirector">
              <li><a href="#"><span>Assistante Director</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="departments cf">                             
              <li><a href="#"><span>Administration</span></a></li>

              <li class="department dep-a">
                <a href="#"><span>Department A</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A1</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A2</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A3</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A4</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A5</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="department dep-b">
                <a href="#"><span>Department B</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B1</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B2</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B3</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B4</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="department dep-c">
                <a href="#"><span>Department C</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C1</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C2</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C3</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C4</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="department dep-d">
                <a href="#"><span>Department D</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D1</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D2</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D3</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D4</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D5</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D6</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="department dep-e">
                <a href="#"><span>Department E</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section E1</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section E2</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section E3</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>   
      </li>
    </ul>           
  </figure>
</div>


/* CSS */
*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}

/* Generic styling */

body{
    background: #F5EEC9;    
}

.content{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1142px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

a:focus{
    outline: 2px dashed #f7f7f7;
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px){
    .content{
        padding: 0 20px;
    }   
}

ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;       
}

ul a{
    display: block;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: .7em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    height: 70px;
    margin-bottom: -26px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-transition: all linear .1s;
    -moz-transition: all linear .1s;
    transition: all linear .1s;
}


@media all and (max-width: 767px){
    ul a{
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}


ul a span{
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -0.7em;
    display: block;
}

/*

 */

.administration > li > a{
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.director > li > a{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 0px auto;
}

.subdirector:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 130px;
    background: red;
    border-left: 4px solid #fff;
    left: 45.45%;
    position: relative;
}

.subdirector,
.departments{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.subdirector > li:first-child,
.departments > li:first-child{  
    width: 18.59894921190893%;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 0 auto 92px auto;       
    padding-top: 25px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid white;
    z-index: 1; 
}

.subdirector > li:first-child{
    float: right;
    right: 27.2%;
    border-left: 4px solid white;
}

.departments > li:first-child{  
    float: left;
    left: 27.2%;
    border-right: 4px solid white;  
}

.subdirector > li:first-child a,
.departments > li:first-child a{
    width: 100%;
}

.subdirector > li:first-child a{    
    left: 25px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px){
    .subdirector > li:first-child,
    .departments > li:first-child{
        width: 40%; 
    }

    .subdirector > li:first-child{
        right: 10%;
        margin-right: 2px;
    }

    .subdirector:after{
        left: 49.8%;
    }

    .departments > li:first-child{
        left: 10%;
        margin-left: 2px;
    }
}


.departments > li:first-child a{
    right: 25px;
}

.department:first-child,
.departments li:nth-child(2){
    margin-left: 0;
    clear: left;    
}

.departments:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 81.1%;
    height: 22px;   
    border-top: 4px solid #fff;
    border-right: 4px solid #fff;
    border-left: 4px solid #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 130px;
    left: 9.1%
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px){
    .departments:after{
        border-right: none;
        left: 0;
        width: 49.8%;
    }  
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px){
    .department:first-child:before,
   .department:last-child:before{
    border:none;
  }
}

.department:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 22px;
    border-left: 4px solid white;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -22px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -4px;
}

.department{
    border-left: 4px solid #fff;
    width: 18.59894921190893%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.751313485113835%;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.lt-ie8 .department{
    width: 18.25%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px){
    .department{
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .department:before{
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 60px;
        border-left: 4px solid white;
        z-index: 1;
        top: -60px;
        left: 0%;
        margin-left: -4px;
    }

    .department:nth-child(2):before{
        display: none;
    }
}

.department > a{
    margin: 0 0 -26px -4px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.department > a:hover{  
    height: 80px;
}

.department > ul{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.department li{ 
    padding-left: 25px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    height: 80px;   
}

.department li a{
    background: #fff;
    top: 48px;  
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 90%;
    height: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    right: -1px;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%) !important;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.25)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0)))!important;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)!important;
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)!important;
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)!important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)!important;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#40000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1 );
}

.department li a:hover{
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 9px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    height: 80px;
    width: 95%;
    top: 39px;
    background-image: none!important;
}

/* Department/ section colors */
.department.dep-a a{ background: #FFD600; }
.department.dep-b a{ background: #AAD4E7; }
.department.dep-c a{ background: #FDB0FD; }
.department.dep-d a{ background: #A3A2A2; }
.department.dep-e a{ background: #f0f0f0; }
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like: http://www.getorgchart.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [suggestion you linked to](http://codepen.io/siiron/pen/aLkdE) isn't too hard to edit.  If you remove a department, you can make the following CSS changes to fix the chart:

```
@media all and (min-width: 768px){
    /* this removes the top connector from the first li */
    /*.department:first-child:before,*/
    /* need to remove it from first department (second li) */
    .department:nth-child(2):before,
   .department:last-child:before{
    border:none;
  }
}
```

and

```
.department{
    border-left: 4px solid #fff;
    /* width: 18.59894921190893%; */
    /* use the calc() function and set the divisor to the number of departments  */
    width: calc(92% / 4);
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.751313485113835%;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

**Here's a demo**

```css
*{
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: relative;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}

/* Generic styling */

body{
 background: #F5EEC9; 
}

.content{
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1142px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 20px;
}

a:focus{
 outline: 2px dashed #f7f7f7;
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px){
 .content{
  padding: 0 20px;
 } 
}

ul{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;  
}

ul a{
 display: block;
 background: #ccc;
 border: 4px solid #fff;
 text-align: center;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-size: .7em;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #333;
 height: 70px;
 margin-bottom: -26px;
 box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 -webkit-transition: all linear .1s;
 -moz-transition: all linear .1s;
 transition: all linear .1s;
}


@media all and (max-width: 767px){
 ul a{
  font-size: 1em;
 }
}


ul a span{
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -0.7em;
 display: block;
}

/*
 
 */

.administration > li > a{
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.director > li > a{
 width: 50%;
 margin: 0 auto 0px auto;
}

.subdirector:after{
 content: "";
 display: block;
 width: 0;
 height: 130px;
 background: red;
 border-left: 4px solid #fff;
 left: 45.45%;
 position: relative;
}

.subdirector,
.departments{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
}

.subdirector > li:first-child,
.departments > li:first-child{ 
 width: 18.59894921190893%;
 height: 64px;
 margin: 0 auto 92px auto;  
 padding-top: 25px;
 border-bottom: 4px solid white;
 z-index: 1; 
}

.subdirector > li:first-child{
 float: right;
 right: 27.2%;
 border-left: 4px solid white;
}

.departments > li:first-child{ 
 float: left;
 left: 27.2%;
 border-right: 4px solid white; 
}

.subdirector > li:first-child a,
.departments > li:first-child a{
 width: 100%;
}

.subdirector > li:first-child a{ 
 left: 25px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px){
 .subdirector > li:first-child,
 .departments > li:first-child{
  width: 40%; 
 }

 .subdirector > li:first-child{
  right: 10%;
  margin-right: 2px;
 }

 .subdirector:after{
  left: 49.8%;
 }

 .departments > li:first-child{
  left: 10%;
  margin-left: 2px;
 }
}


.departments > li:first-child a{
 right: 25px;
}

.department:first-child,
.departments li:nth-child(2){
 margin-left: 0;
 clear: left; 
}

.departments:after{
 content: "";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 81.1%;
 height: 22px; 
 border-top: 4px solid #fff;
 border-right: 4px solid #fff;
 border-left: 4px solid #fff;
 margin: 0 auto;
 top: 130px;
 left: 9.1%
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px){
 .departments:after{
  border-right: none;
  left: 0;
  width: 49.8%;
 }  
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px){
    /* this removes the top connector from the first li */
 /*.department:first-child:before,*/
    /* need to remove it from first department (second li) */
 .department:nth-child(2):before,
   .department:last-child:before{
    border:none;
  }
}

.department:before{
 content: "";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 22px;
 border-left: 4px solid white;
 z-index: 1;
 top: -22px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -4px;
}

.department{
 border-left: 4px solid #fff;
 /* width: 18.59894921190893%; */
    /* use the calc() function and set the divisor to the number of departments  */
    width: calc(92% / 4);
 float: left;
 margin-left: 1.751313485113835%;
 margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.lt-ie8 .department{
 width: 18.25%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px){
 .department{
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
 }

 .department:before{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 60px;
  border-left: 4px solid white;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -60px;
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: -4px;
 }

 .department:nth-child(2):before{
  display: none;
 }
}

.department > a{
 margin: 0 0 -26px -4px;
 z-index: 1;
}

.department > a:hover{ 
 height: 80px;
}

.department > ul{
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.department li{ 
 padding-left: 25px;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
 height: 80px; 
}

.department li a{
 background: #fff;
 top: 48px; 
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 width: 90%;
 height: 60px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 right: -1px;
 background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%) !important;
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.25)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0)))!important;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)!important;
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)!important;
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)!important;
 background-image: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)!important;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#40000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1 );
}

.department li a:hover{
 box-shadow: 8px 8px 9px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 height: 80px;
 width: 95%;
 top: 39px;
 background-image: none!important;
}

/* Department/ section colors */
.department.dep-a a{ background: #FFD600; }
.department.dep-b a{ background: #AAD4E7; }
.department.dep-c a{ background: #FDB0FD; }
.department.dep-d a{ background: #A3A2A2; }
.department.dep-e a{ background: #f0f0f0; }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>Responsive Organization Chart</h1>
  <figure class="org-chart cf">
    <ul class="administration">
      <li>     
        <ul class="director">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><span>Director</span></a>
            <ul class="subdirector">
              <li><a href="#"><span>Assistante Director</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="departments cf">        
              <li><a href="#"><span>Administration</span></a></li>
              
              <li class="department dep-a">
                <a href="#"><span>Department A</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A1</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A2</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A3</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A4</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A5</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="department dep-b">
                <a href="#"><span>Department B</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B1</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B2</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B3</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B4</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="department dep-c">
                <a href="#"><span>Department C</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C1</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C2</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C3</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C4</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <!-- remove enter department list item -->
              <!-- <li class="department dep-d">
                <a href="#"><span>Department D</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D1</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D2</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D3</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D4</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D5</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D6</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li> -->
              <!-- remove enter department list item -->
              <li class="department dep-e">
                <a href="#"><span>Department E</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section E1</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section E2</span></a></li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section E3</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul> 
      </li>
    </ul>   
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly for right now. I tried a few things when editing the CSS but all I got was weird reactions. I didn't see the stuff .department you saw. I was also trying to remove department E which, as I see, removing D makes more sense? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure there's something better out there.  Something that's generated would be nice.

Comment: Hmmmm, I was able to remove any department and it seemed to work still.

Comment: Ah I see. When I was trying I was essentially taking Department E away but I could only get the connecting bars to adjust over while the other 4 departments stood still. Now I am in the process of mimicking code to convert some of the extra ones into nodes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know what needs to be done to convert some of the sections into nodes, would you? Essentially, I just want smaller sections attached to each current section underneath.

Comment: I would think it should be fairly similar to how the current sections are displayed under each department.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Glorygram, a JS open source library:

https://github.com/benjaminrathelot/glorygram